# Subscribe getting observable return undefined

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am creating an observer, and at some point I am throwing an error with observer.error('some error')

But in subscribe the error comes undefined. Does anyone know what may be happening?

Below the code:

```
  private getUserDataAndroid(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([
                this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ]).then(result => {
                if (!result.hasPermission) {
                    observer.error('some error'); 
...
```

```
  this.getUserDataAndroid().subscribe(user => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                this.storageProvider.salvarUsuario(user);
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(PaginaInicialPage);
            }, error => {
                console.log(error); // HERE THE ERROR IS UNDEFINED

               this.showMessageLoginError();
            });
```

Comment: Strange that you are calling **then** on an **Observable** - which is for a promise not an Observable. I am surprised that even runs without an error. Try handling `!result.hasPermission` in your subscriber, without calling `then()`.

Comment: actually the **then** is calling from the **this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions** method, not from observable that I'm creating

Comment: I wouldn't mix up observables and promises like this, you will get very confused. Also, you could try **throwError** with Observables, that is the proper way.